How can I change the audio output in Telegram on iOS during a call from speakers to Bluetooth headphones?
I want to change the audio output in Telegram on iOS during a call from speakers to Bluetooth headphones. How to do so?
My Bluetooth headphones are connected, but I don't see the option during the call:

I use an  iPhone 12 mini.


Click on the iPhone's side button to lock the iPhone.

Unlock the iPhone.

Click on Audio:


Select Bluetooth headphones:



